# Excel "file in a file" gone after saving

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am trying to help my friend.

In a folder, she has 2 files - "file2015.xls" and "file2016.xls". She claims that when opening "file2016.xls", there was a window inside Excel to switch between "file2016.xls" and "file2017.xls", although the latter file was never present inside the folder? Yesterday, when she was working on "file2017.xls", she saved it and the "window for switching between files" went missing. It is like the file is gone.

What is strange is the file size. These files are basically reports and they have the same layout and amount of data, just the numbers are different. Yet, "file2016.xls" is 2 times bigger than "file2015.xls". But I cannot find data from "file2017.xls" inside of "file2016.xls". Can anyone explain what had happened? She is using Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

### First attempt, possible problem

There are /2016\ and /2017\ sheets in the file and the sheet-tabs are not shown.

Make sure that the "Show sheet tabs" option is enabled.

To do this, for at least some Excel versions, click File > Options > Advanced, and look under Display options for the workbook; make sure the Show sheet tabs check box is selected.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-are-my-worksheet-tabs-42623d50-2f9b-4583-ad9c-f1b381185e48

### Second attempt, locate the file if it exists

> when she was working on "file2017.xls", she saved it and the "window for switching between files" went missing. It is like the file is gone.

Hold the left "Windows (flag)" key and press <kbd>R</kbd>
type `cmd` and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
a `C:\...>` prompt appears, where the ... portion varies with Windows version and the logged in user.

now type
`dir /s /b C:\ | find /i "file2017.xls"`
... to try to locate "file2017.xls" - if it ever was saved.

You might need to repeat this for all disks/partitions, e.g. D:\ E:\ ... Z:\ that exists on the computer.

**To find out which disks exists/partitions you HAVE**; Hold the left "Windows (flag)" key and press <kbd>E</kbd> to launch the File explorer and check in the left side pane (you might need to open the pane, hold ALT and look in the View-menu after that option).

Comment: No, I forgot to mention that each file has 5 sheets and they are all visible. So, it is not about the sheets ...

Comment: ok. No more ideas about that then, added text to help locate the file, if it WAS saved.